# Regex to check more than 3 occurrences of numbers separated by non-numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

How would you write a regex that tests for more than 3 occurrences of numbers separated by non-numbers.

**Valid:**

```
"abcd"
"abcd123abcd"
"123ab.cd"
"123a+bcd123xx999"
"8x8x8"
```

**Not valid:**

```
"8x8x8x8"
"123abcd123xx999x9"
"a9a9a9a9a"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
/^(\d{0,}\D{0,}){0,3}$/
```

Comment: Nice one! You could write that `/\A(?:\d*\D*){,3}\z/`, where `\A` and `\z` are start and end of string anchors, rather than start and end of line anchors (`^` and `$`):  `"1a2b3c\n4".match?(/^(?:\d*\D*){,3}$/) #=> true; "1a2b3c\n4".match?(/\A(?:\d*\D*){,3}\z/) #=> false`. None of the examples had embedded newlines, but they were not expressly prohibited.

Answer (score 3):

Here I prefer using a simple regex and a few methods to using a single, relatively-complex regex.

**Code**

```
def no_more_than?(str, n)
  str.scan(/\d+/).size <= n
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr =
  %w|abcd abcd123abcd 123ab.cd 123a+bcd123xx999 8x8x8 8x8x8x8 123abcd123xx999x9 a9a9a9a9a|

arr.each do |s|
  puts "#{s.ljust(25)}\#=> #{no_more_than?(s,3)}"
end

abcd                     #=> true
abcd123abcd              #=> true
123ab.cd                 #=> true
123a+bcd123xx999         #=> true
8x8x8                    #=> true
8x8x8x8                  #=> false
123abcd123xx999x9        #=> false
a9a9a9a9a                #=> false
```

Another way is as follows.

```
str.gsub(/\d+/).count <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex to test, i.e. find a string *with* more than 3 occurrences would be

`\d+(?:\D+\d+){3}`

which total's a minimum of:
4 occurrences of numbers, separated by 3 non-numbers.

That's all you need to find since 4 is the target.
I.e. you don't need to make the quantifier `{3,}` because it's a waste of time.

You can deduce then, if it matches, it's *invalid*, since that's all you're testing.